# Swap images with a list of HTML links with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to swap images using JavaScript. I have a main content area the loads one image. I have a sidebar with a list of links and I want to use JavaScript to change the image with each link. here is my code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Rat Dog Inc. ~ Services</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myImg;
var myImage= [];
myImage[0] = "../images/rd_surf_large.jpg";
myImage[1] = "../images/laundry.png";
myImage[2] = "../images/tug-o-war.png";
myImage[3] = "../images/cuddlepuppy.png";
myImage[4] = "../images/rd-howling.mp4";
function displayImg(){
    document.getElementById('myImage[]');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="main">
    <img src="../images/rd_surf_large.png"  alt="Rat Dog Inc." id="myImg"/>
</div>
<div id="sidebar">
  <h2>Rat Dog Inc. Most Popular Services</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" onClick="displayImg(myImage[0]);">Surfing Lessons</a>       <span style="font-size: 12px">(img)</span></li>
      <li><a href="#" onClick="displayImg(myImage[1]);">Laundry Folding</a>  <span style="font-size: 12px">(img)</span></li>
      <li><a href="#" onClick="displayImg(myImage[2]);">Tug-O-War Arm Workouts</a> <span style="font-size: 12px">(img)</span></li>
      <li><a href="#" onClick="displayImg(myImage[3]);">Cuddling</a> <span style="font-size: 12px">(img)</span></li>
      <li><a href="#" onClick="displayImg(myImage[4]);">Howling Lessons</a>       <span style="font-size: 12px">(video)</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Since the images are in the server, if you need to load one new image every time you click a link, you have to make a request to the server for the new image and that will essentially reload the image. If you don't want to reload the page after eack click for image links, I can suggest two ways:
1. Load all images beforehand and set display style blank for all but one. Then using JS every time you click a link, make that corresponding image visible and rest hidden.
2. Make ajax calls for new image on link click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. So here's the deal.
When you put your image on your page , like this:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="myImage">
```

And we assign the I'd 'myImage' to it....if we want to change the image via a link (I prefare a button), we use javascript in a way to manipulate it.
You simply use this method known as :

```
document.getElementById()
```

Which finds an element in our page by its I'd.
So if we put this button on our page:

```
<button onclick="changeImage()">Change The Image</button>
```

And put this script (which has the changeImage() function) :

```
<script>
function changeImage(){
 var myImage = document.getElementById("myImage");
//then we change the src of the image
myImage.src="image2.jpg"
}
</script>
```

Our image will change of we click the button.

For reference , please visit http://www.htmldog.com/guides/javascript/intermediate/thedom

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

please try and use this method of getElementById

For example:

```
<img id="image" src="image1.jpg">
<button onclick="changeToImage2('image')">Image 2</button>
<script>
function changeToImage(id) {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(id);
    myImage.src = "image2.jpg";
}
// then create other buttons and other functions to change the image.
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm not sure i am understanding.. I am not very good with javaScript so i need more of a breakdown pretty please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementById("image").src="image.png";` to change the `src` tag of an element.

Although for what you are doing, I reccomend you take a look at [jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/%20%22jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is incorrect. I'm not quite sure you understand how it works.

First of all, your function doesn't accept any parameters, and yet you're providing it with one. It will just ignore this because it doesn't know what to do with it.

Next, your `document.getElementById` in your `displayImg()` has the wrong input. Right now it's literally looking for an element with the ID "**myImage[]**"... of which there are none.

Also, you have a variable you never use (**myImg**). You should probably get rid of it.

Again, I'm getting the sense that you don't really know javascript that well or don't get the theory behind it. If you need help, [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp) has some great tutorials.